# Mapbox GL JS : Drag 1 point in many points map

Tags: drag, point, mapbox-gl-js

We have a requirement where-in we have to provide drag drop facility for markers / points. The example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/ works perfect for 1 marker. **Because it is hardcoded to geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = [coords.lng, coords.lat];**

However, in a multi point scenario how to set the geojson for respective feature which was dragged?

Kindly let know if any further details required.

Thankx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by storing the current marker and applying the change on it during onMove.

I have added a property to each object to define an `id`:

```js
var geojson = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [0, 0]
      },
      properties: {
       id: 1
      }
    },
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [0, 1]
      },
      properties: {
       id: 2
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

On the `onmousedown` event on point layer, store the current feature id

> Here `features[0]` is usable because the event fired on point so the first feature is ever the clicked one

```js
map.on("mousedown", "point", function(e) {

    currentFeatureId = e.features[0].properties.id;
    // Prevent the default map drag behavior.
    e.preventDefault();
    canvas.style.cursor = "grab";

    map.on("mousemove", onMove);
    map.once("mouseup", onUp);
});
```

After that, in the `onMove` method you can use it to move the right feature :

```js
function onMove(e) {
    var coords = e.lngLat;

    // Set a UI indicator for dragging.
    canvas.style.cursor = "grabbing";

    // Update the Point feature in `geojson` coordinates
    // and call setData to the source layer `point` on it.
    var currentMarker = geojson.features.find(obj => {
        return obj.properties.id === currentFeatureId
    })
    currentMarker.geometry.coordinates = [coords.lng, coords.lat];
    map.getSource("point").setData(geojson);
}
```

See working exemple here : https://codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/moxmpZ

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Where did you find the features property of the event? It don't see that in the documentation for the MouseEvent.

Comment: Don't forget to define the `touchstart` event to make it work on touch screens.